# "AT TIME ZONE" with zone name PostgreSQL bug?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I was answering this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961732/osx-postgres-9-1-4-timestamp-with-time-zone-order-by) question and found strange result:

```
 select * from  pg_timezone_names where name = 'Europe/Berlin' ;
     name      | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
---------------+--------+------------+--------
 Europe/Berlin | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
```

and next query

```
select id, 
  timestampwithtimezone, 
  timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as berlin, 
  timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'CET' as cet 
from data ;
 id  | timestampwithtimezone  |       berlin        |         cet         
 -----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 205 | 2012-10-28 01:30:00+02 | 2012-10-28 01:30:00 | 2012-10-28 00:30:00
 204 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+02 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00 | 2012-10-28 01:00:00
 203 | 2012-10-28 02:30:00+02 | 2012-10-28 02:30:00 | 2012-10-28 01:30:00
 202 | 2012-10-28 02:59:59+02 | 2012-10-28 02:59:59 | 2012-10-28 01:59:59
 106 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+01 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.2 and ubuntu 12.04.
Just checked that on 8.2.11 result is the same.

According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) it doesn't matter if I use name or abbreviation.

Is this a bug?
Am I doing something wrong?
Can someone explain this result?

**EDIT**
For the comment that CET is not Europe/Berlin.

I'm just selecting values from pg_timezone_names.

```
select * from  pg_timezone_names  where abbrev ='CEST';
 name | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
------+--------+------------+--------
```

and

```
select * from  pg_timezone_names  where abbrev ='CET';
        name         | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
---------------------+--------+------------+--------
 Africa/Tunis        | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 Africa/Algiers      | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 Africa/Ceuta        | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 CET                 | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 Atlantic/Jan_Mayen  | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 Arctic/Longyearbyen | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 Poland              | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 .....
```

During winter Europe/Berlin is +01. During summer it is +02.

**EDIT2**
In 2012-10-28 timezone has change from summer time to winter time at 2:00.
This two records have the same value in Europe/Berlin:

```
204 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+02 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00 | 2012-10-28 01:00:00
106 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+01 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00
```

This suggest that if I use one of abbreviations (CET or CEST) for big data range (summer time and winter time) result will be wrong for some of records. Will be good if I use 'Europe/Berlin'.

I changed the system time to '2012-01-17' and pg_timezone_names has changed also.

```
select * from  pg_timezone_names  where name ='Europe/Berlin';
     name      | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst 
---------------+--------+------------+--------
 Europe/Berlin | CEST   | 02:00:00   | t
```

Comment: It is quite sure that `2012-10-28 01:30:00` is CEST, not CET.

Comment: As far as I know `CET` is **not** `Europe/Berlin` - at least not during DST times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the documentation says clearly that the time zone name and abbreviation will behave differently.

> In short, this is the difference between abbreviations and full names:
>   abbreviations always represent a fixed offset from UTC, whereas most
>   of the full names imply a local daylight-savings time rule, and so
>   have two possible UTC offsets. [Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

FWIW, that same reference also says

> We do not recommend using the type time with time zone (though it is
>   supported by PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance
>   with the SQL standard).

Answer (score 6):

And that's still not the gist of it! I ran into [a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to) some time ago.

The major cons of time zone abbreviations have been presented here already: they do not take DST (daylight saving time) into account. The major pro: simplicity resulting in superior **performance**. Taking DST rules into account makes time zone names *slow* in comparison. Time zone abbreviations are simple, symbolic time offsets, time zone names are subject to a constantly changing set of rules. I ran benchmarks in [this related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234230/939860), the difference is remarkable. But when applied to a set, it's typically *necessary* to use time zone names to cover possibly different DST status per row (and also historic differences).

We are talking about **CET**. The really tricky part is that "CET" is not only (obviously) a **time zone abbreviation**, it is *also* a **time zone name**, at least according to my installation (PostgreSQL 9.1.6 on Debian Squeeze with locale "de_AT.UTF-8") and all others I have seen so far. I mention these details, because Postgres uses the locale information of the underlying OS if available.

See for yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE name = 'CET';

SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_abbrevs WHERE abbrev = 'CET';
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6683)

Postgres picks the abbreviation over the full name. So, even though I found CET in the *time zone names*, the expression `'2012-01-18 01:00 CET'::timestamptz` is interpreted according to the subtly different rules for *time zone abbreviations*.

If that's not a loaded footgun I don't know what is.

To avoid ambiguities, go with the time zone name 'Europe/Berlin' (or 'Europe/Vienna' in my case - which is effectively the same, except for historic differences). Find more details on the topic under the [closely related question I mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to).

In closing, I would like to voice my deeply felt contempt for the moronic concept of DST. It should be removed from existence and never spoken of again.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
select  
    '2012-10-28 02:30:00+02'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as berlin,
    '2012-10-28 02:30:00+02'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'CET' as cet,
    '2012-10-28 02:30:00+02'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'CEST' as cest
```

`+02` is CEST in Berlin, not CET.