# Strange UTC offset time zone parsing in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone

Postgres exhibits some strange behaviour when parsing time zones, or I just don't understand how it works.

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT):

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'MST';
> Result: 2001-02-16 18:38:40
> ```
>
> The example takes a time stamp specified in EST (UTC-5) and converts it to local time in MST (UTC-7).

This *seems* to imply that 'MST' is interchangeable with 'UTC-7' but the behaviour is opposite to what you'd expect.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC-7';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40
```

Instead of using the time zone 'UTC-7' it's using 'UTC+7', which is 14 hours different.

Using ISO 8601 time zone notation also yields the opposite from the expected result:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE '-7';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE '-07';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE '-07:00';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40
```

The only ISO 8601 notation that threw an error was the `-0700` notation.

Other gibberish notations *are* accepted, even though they don't make any sense at all:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE '-7MST';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'MST-7';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE '-7+7';
Result: 2001-02-17 08:38:40
```

Can someone help me understand how time zones, specifically offset notation works, or is supposed to work, in Postgres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["AT TIME ZONE" with zone name PostgreSQL bug?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30787/at-time-zone-with-zone-name-postgresql-bug)

Comment: I read that one before posting, but it didn't seem to address the issue of UTC offset notation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Instead of using the time zone 'UTC-7' it's using 'UTC+7', which is 14 hours different.***

It depends whether +/- means east or west of Greenwich, and it turns out both conventions exist. PostgreSQL doc warns about that:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Excerpt from *8.5.3. Time Zones* (but you really want to read the whole paragraph):

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names,
>   positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere
>   else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive
>   timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

***Using ISO 8601 time zone notation also yields the opposite from the expected result:***

In the same page, the accepted formats for time zone literals are listed, here's a condensed version:

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - A full time zone name, for example America/New_York [...]
> - A time zone abbreviation, for example PST[...]
> - In addition to the timezone names and abbreviations, PostgreSQL will accept POSIX-style time zone specifications of the form STDoffset
>     or STDoffsetDST, where STD is a zone abbreviation, offset is a numeric
>     offset in hours west from UTC, and DST is an optional daylight-savings
>     zone abbreviation,[...]

Note that it never pretends to accept an ISO 8601 time zone designator. And as you found out with `-0700`, it doesn't. You should just use one of the forms above.

Also beware of (false) conclusions that because the parser doesn't reject a time zone, it's valid:

> One should be wary that the POSIX-style time zone feature can lead to
>   silently accepting bogus input, since there is no check on the
>   reasonableness of the zone abbreviations

Comment: Thank you, I checked the `AT TIME ZONE` documentation, but didn't think to check the date/time documentation. I'll just stick to the named time zones for my own sanity.