# SET TIME ZONE '-7' vs. AT TIME ZONE '-7'

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, timezone

This is similar to these questions:

- [Why does PostgreSQL interpret numeric UTC offset as POSIX and not ISO-8601?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215905/why-does-postgresql-interpret-numeric-utc-offset-as-posix-and-not-iso-8601)
- [Strange UTC offset time zone parsing in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130546/strange-utc-offset-time-zone-parsing-in-postgres)

I'm running Postgres 10.3. As per the docs, many time zone descriptors are interpreted as POSIX, which calculates negative offsets **east** of UTC while ISO 8601 interprets negative offsets **west** of UTC. But then this:

```
SET TIME ZONE '-7';
SHOW TIME ZONE;
>> <-07>+07
SELECT NOW();
>> 2018-09-26 12:00:20.309182-07
SELECT NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'
>> 2018-09-26 12:00:22.445955
SELECT NOW() AT TIME ZONE '-7'
>> 2018-09-27 02:00:27.862773
```

It appears that '-7' is interpreted as ISO 8601 when used in `SET TIME ZONE '-7'` and as POSIX when used in `AT TIME ZONE '-7'`.

Is there a reason for this? Is it documented somewhere?